# ImageMagick creating thumbnail

Tags: php, html, imagemagick, imagick

here is code which creats animated text using imagemagick..

```
$label=$_POST["label"];
$cmd = " -background transparent -font $font -pointsize $size label:$label -stroke black -strokewidth 2 ".
"  \( -clone 0 -tile \"" . $image . "[0]\" -stroke black -strokewidth 2 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 $label \) ".
```

the above code wokrs fine when i enter "1234" in label field ... but it doe not when i type"12 34" it displays only "12" it is not taking "space" in between charcter ...something needs to be done for  "label" variable.. not sure how to fix this.. please help me to resolve this...

Comment: You directly inject post variables into the commandline. This is a [remote command injection vulnerability](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Command_Injection). Please see [`escapeshellarg`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) which also solves your original problem. You're lucky it did blow early.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the entire string in double quotes since spaces are not allowed in command line. In the following i enclosed both usages of `$label` in double-quotes using the `\"` escape sequence:

```
$label=$_POST["label"];
$cmd = " -background transparent -font $font -pointsize $size label:\"$label\" -stroke black -strokewidth 2 ".
"  \( -clone 0 -tile \"" . $image . "[0]\" -stroke black -strokewidth 2 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 \"$label\" \) ".
```

Comment: @user1120557: Good! Now if one of the posts helped you, you should "accept" that post, i.e click the check mark below its score. If none of the posts were helpful to you, then you might want to add an answer to your question explaining what worked, and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

My post is editted. See what hakre posted, it's a [better answer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) than mine was.

```
string escapeshellarg ( string $arg )
```

Should do the trick, plus it allows you to pass a string directly to the shell function treated as a single safe argument

Answer (score 0):

Use apostrophes, like in example "Labels over Multiple Lines" at http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#label

```
$cmd = " -background transparent -font $font -pointsize $size label:'$label' -stroke black -strokewidth 2 ".
```